# Google Cloud Shell - How to resolve CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-shell

I have simple dataflow pipeline and trying to execute from cloud shell,

**Code:**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) as p:
    lines = p | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('test.csv')
    lines | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://bucket/output_20193003', file_name_suffix='.csv')
    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()
```

**Command used to execute:**

```
python -m simple_pipeline --runner DataflowRunner --project myproject --staging_location gs://bucket/staging --temp_location gs://bucket/temp
```

**Observations:**
When executed from Cloud shell I encounter below error,

```
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner.py", line 859, in run_stages
    pcoll_buffers, safe_coders).process_bundle.metrics
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner.py", line 970, in run_stage
    self._progress_frequency).process_bundle(data_input, data_output)
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner.py", line 1174, in process_bundle
    result_future = self._controller.control_handler.push(process_bundle)
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner.py", line 1054, in push
    response = self.worker.do_instruction(request)
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 208, in do_instruction
    request.instruction_id)
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 230, in process_bundle
    processor.process_bundle(instruction_id)
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 301, in process_bundle
    op.finish()
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 398, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 399, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 400, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 598, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.finish
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 589, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 618, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 587, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 299, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 302, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 693, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.finish_bundle_outputs
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/iobase.py", line 1005, in finish_bundle
    yield WindowedValue(self.writer.close(), window.MAX_TIMESTAMP,
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsink.py", line 388, in close
    self.sink.close(self.temp_handle)
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsink.py", line 148, in close
    file_handle.close()
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystemio.py", line 201, in close
    self._uploader.finish()
  File "/home/user/beam-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 553, in finish
    raise self._upload_thread.last_error  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
RuntimeError: SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661) [while running 'Write/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles']
```

**Note:** I see this error only from Cloud Shell and the same code and commands works fine when executed from local machine - Using SDK or PyCharm IDE.

What is the problem with my cloud shell? How to fix it? Please suggest.

Comment: Is it really "gs://bucket" you are using as the GCS bucket for your write?  If so, that doesn't feel correct.

Comment: No. The actual bucket name is different.

Comment: Would you mind restarting your cloud shell, and checking if that makes the error go away? https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#resetting_cloud_shell_to_default_state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to launch dataflow jobs after upgrading to latest version.

```
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this in cloud shell?

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2 run_pipeline
. ./run_pipeline/bin/activate
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
python -m simple_pipeline --runner DataflowRunner --project myproject --staging_location gs://bucket/staging --temp_location gs://bucket/temp
```

Comment: I exactly followed same steps but was specifying apache-beam[gcp]==2.5.0